# How to build a Fat Framework that includes Mac Catalyst?

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode11, mac-catalyst

How does one build a fat framework that includes the architectures necessary to build to Mac Catalyst apps?

Answer (score 7):

Apple has introduced a (undocumented?) new target: `x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi`

How to build for this target depends on your frameworks build environment.

**1) XCFramework**

In case your framework is an Xcode project:

- Select the target in Xcode
- Select the "General" tab
- Under "Deployment Info", tick the "Mac" checkbox:
  [image]
- build

**2) External Build**

In case you are building your framework outside Xcode, e.g. a C lib, instead of building for x86_64 & iphonesimulator, build for the new target x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi & macosx.

Example for C Lib using make:

```
MIN_IOS_VERSION="10.0"
LIB_NAME= "theNameOfYourLib"

# The build function
build()
{
ARCH=$1
TARGET=$2
HOST=$3
SDK=$4
SDK_PATH=`xcrun -sdk ${SDK} --show-sdk-path`

export PREFIX=build/${ARCH}
export CFLAGS="-arch ${ARCH} -isysroot ${SDK_PATH} -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_IOS_VERSION} -std=c99 -target ${TARGET}"
export LDFLAGS="-arch ${ARCH}"
export CC="$(xcrun --sdk ${SDK} -f clang) -arch ${ARCH} -isysroot ${SDK_PATH}"

PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1 PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig ./configure --host=${HOST} --prefix=$PREFIX

make
make install
}

# Build for all required architectures

build "armv7" "armv7-apple-ios" "arm-apple-darwin" "iphoneos" # MIN_IOS_VERSION must be one of arm7 supported ones to. Else remove this line.
build "arm64" "aarch64-apple-ios" "arm-apple-darwin" "iphoneos"
# build "x86_64" "x86_64-apple-ios" "x86_64-apple-darwin" "iphonesimulator" #obsolete due to x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi
build "x86_64" "x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi" "x86_64-apple-darwin" "macosx"
build "i386" "i386-apple-ios" "i386-apple-darwin" "iphonesimulator" # same as arm7:  MIN_IOS_VERSION must be one of arm7 supported ones.

# Now find all the artefacts created above (e.g. build/arm64/lib/${LIB_NAME}.a,  build/x86_64/lib/${LIB_NAME}.a ...) and merge them together to a fat lib using lipo

OUTPUT_DIR="fatLib"
lipo -create -output $OUTPUT_DIR/lib/${LIB_NAME}.a build/x86_64/lib/${LIB_NAME}.a build/arm64/lib/${LIB_NAME}.a build/armv7/lib/${LIB_NAME}.a build/i386/lib/${LIB_NAME}.a

# You may also need the header files
cp -R build/armv7/include/* $OUTPUT_DIR/include/
```

---

**Note:** You must/can not add slices for `x86_64-apple-ios` and `x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi`to the fat lib. Both are x86_64. Use only the one for `x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi`.

Comment: I'm building my framework with an Xcode project, but Deployment Info only offers a dropdown list of Mac OS versions. No checkboxes for other platforms.

Comment: @Oscar it must be an IOS framework target. You have a macOS target.

Comment: Thanks. I've reconfigured my project since, so I don't remember exactly how it was set up.

Comment: x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi is no longer present in Xcode 13.3. Use x86_64-apple-ios15.0-macabi now.