# iOS App to MacOS App - (build failed using custom framework)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, x86-64

Trying to run my iOS app as MacOS App,
Unfortunately i'm getting following error:

> “.xcodeproj Building for Mac Catalyst, but the linked and embedded
>   framework **'EasyContact.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator**.
>   You may need to restrict the platforms for which this framework should
>   be linked and embedded in the target editor, or replace it with an
>   XCFramework that supports both platforms.“

My Steps:

1. Building **EasyContact.framework:**

   - (Generic iOS device)
   - **Architectures:** armv7s, armv7, arm64, arm64e, x86_64, x86_64h.
   - Mac target is checked.
   - Build successfully.

[image]

[image]

2. My iOS App: (**Build Error**)

   - **Architectures:** armv7s, armv7, arm64, arm64e, x86_64, x86_64h.
   - Mac target is checked.
   - Build Error.
     [image]

SYSTEM:

- MacOS Catalina 10.15.3v
- xCode 11

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the answer to the following question help: [How to build a Fat Framework that includes Mac Catalyst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703754/how-to-build-a-fat-framework-that-includes-mac-catalyst)?